# Discord JS ban all event banning members but returns no error

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

My server has been overwhelmed by a selfbot attack adding multiple users. I am trying to get my bot to ban all the users (few actual users) on the server but this code on a ready event doesn't seem to work. Any help is greatly appreciated. Currently this code says its banning in console but its not actually banning any of the users. (yes i know this may look bad out of context).

```js
client.guilds.forEach(guild => {
        guild.members.forEach(m => {
            m.ban();
            //log when member is banned in the console
            console.info(`\x1b[37m\x1b[44mINFO\x1b[0m: Banned ${m.user.username}; ID: ${m.id}. (╯°□°）╯︵ ┻━┻`);
        });
    });
```

Comment: Your code in its current state would ban all users in all servers that the bot is currently in. Do not run this code

Comment: What version of discord.js are you using?

Comment: discord.js v 12

Answer (score 1):

Mass banning users via a Bot is considered *[abusive usage](https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/legal)*, and we cannot assist you with it. If you want to clear your guild of members,  Discord gives you the Prune option within Settings -> Members -> Prune which can help you remove a chunk. Please remember that abusing this to "raid" a server is considered abuse.